# Scheme Code to Sort a nested list based on < or > operator passed as function argument

Tags: list, sorting, recursion, nested, scheme

Please help me to write a code in scheme since being a beginner I am having a bit trouble in recursive code:

I want a code like:

1) `(my_fn 'a symbol<?)` should output---> `a`
2)`(my_fn '((((a)) b) c) symbol<?)` ---> '((((a)) b) c)
3)`(my_fn '(1 (20 (3 (4 40) 3) 2) 1) >)` ---->'(40 (20 (4 (3 3) 2) 1) 1)
4)`(my_fn '((((a)) b) c) (lambda (x y) (symbol<? y x)))` Output---> '((((c)) b) a)

Comment: What purpose is there to sort the atomic elements and keep the structure?

Comment: purpose is to write a code that sorts the nested list in either ascending or descending order. The complication I am facing is how to do the sorting on nested list!!

Answer (score 1):

The way to sort the atomic elements is to flatten the list:

```scm
(flatten '(((4) 2) 3)) ; ==> (4 2 3)
```

Then you can use the standard [`list-sort`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-5.html) (R6RS here, for R5RS use [SRFI-95](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-95/srfi-95.html) `sort` instead)

```scm
(list-sort < '(4 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4)
```

Then you need some way of recursing the original structure and for each atomic value you use one of the values in the sorted list instead:

```scm
(restructure '(((4) 2) 3) '(2 3 4)) ; ==> (((2) 3) 4)
```

Here is a version of `restructure` that would work, but it uses mutation:

```scm
;; (restructure '(((a) b) c) '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (((1) 2) 3)
(define (restructure tree elements)
  ;; replaces an atom with the next 
  ;; element in elements
  (define (term x)
    (let ((x (car elements)))
      (set! elements (cdr elements))
      x))

  (accumulate-tree tree term cons '()))
```

Finally you put it all together. A possible implementation would look like this:

```scm
(define (structure-sort < tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (restructure tree 
                   (list-sort < (flatten tree)))
      tree)) ; for atomic values there isn't anything to sort
```

Now. If I have a structure with data you can sort the atomic values in the structure into something that doesn't make sense:

```scm
(structure-sort string<? '("person" ("name" "John") ("number" "555-8907")))
; ==>  ("555-8907" ("John" "name") ("number" "person"))
```